# Option With 2 Arguments in OptParse

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, optparse

I'm trying to do something that looks like this:

```
opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
    opt.banner = "Test"
    opt.separator ""
    opt.on("-t", "--test arg1 arg2", "Test") do |arg1, arg2|
        puts arg1
        puts arg2
    end
end
```

The problem is that it returns the `arg1`, but `arg2` returns `nil`. How to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted way of specifying a **list of values for a given option** is by **repeating that option** (for example the `-D` option as accepted by [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) and C compilers), e.g.

```
my_script.rb --test=arg1 --test=arg2
```

In some cases, the nature of your arguments may be such that you can afford to **use a separator without introducing ambiguity** (for example the `-classpath` option to [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) or, more clearly, the `-o` option to [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)), so if `arg1` and `arg2` can never normally contain a comma `,` then you could also accept e.g.

```
my_script.rb --test=arg1,arg2
```

The code that supports both conventions above would be something along the lines of:

```
require 'optparse'
...
test_vals = []
...
opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
    ...
    opt.on("-t", "--test=arg1[,...]", "Test") do |arg|
        test_vals += arg.split(',')
    end
    ...
end

opt_parser.parse!

puts test_vals.join("\n")
```

Then:

```
$ my_script.rb --test=arg1 --test=arg2
arg1
arg2

$ my_script.rb --test=arg1,arg2
arg1
arg2

$ my_script.rb --test=arg1 --test=arg2,arg3
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

Answer (score 3):

If vladr's answer is acceptable, alternate way is to pass `Array` as third argument to `#on`:

```
require 'optparse'

test_vals = []

opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.banner = "Test"
  opt.separator ""
  opt.on("-t", "--test arg1[,...]", Array, "Test") do |args|
    test_vals += args
  end
end

opt_parser.parse!

puts test_vals.join("\n")
```